# Whats wrong after I click the button the modal form closes?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery, modal-dialog

I am having a problems in uploading an image from a modal form, after I click the upload button the modal form closes and I don't know what happen because the modal closes and in my folder I am expecting an uploaded file but there is non. I am expecting to happen is that after I click the upload button it will automatically display the uploaded image in the modal form, Is my code missing something or what?

Here's the jquery code I use:

```
$(function() {
        $('button').button();
        $('.upload-profile-pic').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload-image.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: { uploadedfile: $('.profile-pic-name').val().trim() },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.new-profile-pic').html(data);
                }
            });
        })
        $('.update-profile-pic').click(function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                width:350,
                modal:true
            });
        });
    });
```

Here's my html form

```
<button class="update-profile-pic">Update Profile Picture</button>
<div id="dialog">
    <p class="new-profile-pic">

    </p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
        <input class="profile-pic-name" name="uploadedfile" type="file">
        <input class="upload-profile-pic" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
    </form>
<div>
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
    <?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo '<img alt="" src="'.$target_path.'">';
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You mean I put buttons: { 'ButtonName': function(){} } in my dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do simple form uploads via ajax submits. You would have to use something like [jquery form submit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#dialog',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        url:   'url: 'upload-image.php',
        type:      'POST',
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit  
    }; 

    $('#dialog form').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

You can refer to [this](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm) example for further customization/changes

Comment: You mean it cannot be fix? And use instead the link that you've provided? hehe. i'll try this :) thanks!

Comment: I have faced the ajax upload issue in the past, but never got it to work the plain ajax submit way